# Delete old Azure Blobs after a day

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to add an Azure Blob Storage rule that files older than a day should be deleted.

I am following this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal however, under portal view steps to follow, `Under Blob service, select Lifecycle Management to view or change your rules.` However, there is no such menu under the Blob Service. I cannot find this menu anywhere to add a new rule. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lifecycle management` is only supported one of the following storage account types(see this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#availability-and-pricing) of the doc):

`General Purpose v2 (GPv2) accounts`, `Blob storage accounts`, and `Premium Block Blob storage accounts`

If not, please consider upgrading to one of them. If you don't want to upgrade, you should write a code to delete them by yourself.

Here is the step to check the account type:

Nav to azure portal -> your storage account -> overview page -> check the Account Kind. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: I upgraded to GPv2 and now I have it. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Done. Had to wait a few minutes for it. Why is my post at -1 ?

Comment: @Cristian, don't worry about that. Somebody may down-vote your question. I just up-voted your question:).